# allocating dynamic memory using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is the sample of my code. I want to create  dynamic character array for storing string.

**Here is my code**:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
      int i , j , n;
      char *ptr;
      printf("enter number of elements \n");
      scanf("%d",&n);
      ptr  = (char *) malloc((n + 1)*sizeof(char));
      for (i = 0;i< n;i++)
      {
        scanf("%c",&ptr[i]);
      }
      for ( i = 0;i <n; i++)
      {
        printf("at %d is %c\n",i,*(ptr + i));
      }
      free(ptr);
    }
```

But when I try to compile and run this code, no character is assigned to memory which is pointed by pointer `p`.

**Here is the output of my program**:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/c): ./test2
enter number of elements 
8
asdfghjk
at 0 is 
at 1 is a
at 2 is s
at 3 is d
at 4 is f
at 5 is g
at 6 is h
at 7 is j
```

Comment: Please [don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?lq=1).

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you can replace allocation with `ptr = malloc(n + 1);`.

Comment: as int main(), you should at least return 0 in the end

Comment: @WayneSudo wrong. Since C99 the return value of `main()` is implicitly `0`.

Comment: There is no pointer `p`

Comment: After `scanf("%d",&n)`, call `scanf` one more time in order to "get rid" of the newline (enter) character that was scanned during the first call to this function.

Comment: Don't cast malloc() and "ptr  = (char *) malloc((n + 1)*sizeof(char));" is the same as malloc((n+1) * 1), this is what you need ?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode thx for correction

Comment: Make sure to null terminate the array of characters after reading them, so that you an use them as a C string.

Answer (score 3):

Leave a space before `%c` in `scanf`-

```
scanf(" %c",&ptr[i]);
```

because there will be `'\n'` left in the buffer after the first `scanf` for`n` as you press `ENTER` after giving value of `n`.

And you don't need to cast result of `malloc`.

As what  *Matt McNabb Sir*  said in his comment ,for that you can do this -

```
 scanf("%*c%c",&ptr[i]);
```

`%*c` will take care of `'\n'` and wont even skip if only `space` is hit.

Comment: He might want to enter spaces and have them count

Comment: @MattMcNabb Please see the edit Sir .I tied to cover your point.

Comment: Actually, that entire loop should be replaced by `fgets(ptr, n + 1, stdin);`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  Actually that is right but then also he will have to take care of `'\n'` .

Comment: @ameyCU yes, no question about that! it's just that `fgets()` makes reading the line simpler.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  Yes I totally agree with you Sir !!